# create objects for loop and pushing them into an array js

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I wish to create an array called allEnemies, which contains "bugs" which belong to a Class "Enemy". I'm trying to do it in a for loop because later on the var "bug" will be modified. The problem is that the objects created "if I'm creating them" don't get into the array "allEnmies". Thank you in advance.

```
var allEnemies = [];

var random_speed = function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (300 - 80)) + 80;
};

var random_y = function() {
    var postions = [60, 143, 226];
    return positions[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
};

var create_enemies = function() {

var bugs = 4;

for (var i = 0; i < bugs; i++) {
    var bug = new Enemy();
    bug.speed = random_speed();
    bug.y = random_y();
    bug.x = 0;
    allEnemies.push(bug);
}
};
```

Comment: Where is the `Enemy` prototype?  Where do you call `create_enemies()`?

Comment: This seems jsFiddle sized for sure -

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that there are a few enemies created whenever you use an underscore in a variable... jajajaja   ; )

Comment: You spelled `positions` wrong in `var postions = [60, 143, 226];`.

Comment: See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ykoxqx46/) created a working fiddle with blank 'Enemy' function.

Comment: @AshokVishwakarma - A blank `Enemy` constructor is fine...that's not the same as no `Enemy` constructor. A blank constructor just doesn't initialise anything...a non-existant constructor tells the code there's a problem since it's not expecting to see an `Enemy` object...it doesn't know what it is.

Comment: @Alvin try adding Enemy function body to the fiddle I have created, it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ubkusb6r/

Ok, so a few things:

1) Since you've declared the `for` loop using an anonymous function assigned to a variable **you need to invoke the function via that variable `create_enemies()`**. Without this, your code won't run.

2) You need to create an Ememy constructor (if you haven't done so yet).

3) You misspell `positions` at one place in your code...leading to an error.

Take a look at the JSFiddle and let me know if it answers your question (the fiddle includes console.log statements to track the array).

Comment: He probably just didn't include the `Enemy` constructor for brevity in the question. I'll bet it's the misspelling that's the real problem.

Comment: I think the lack of the `create_enemies()` invocation was the real problem.

Comment: Yep, both cause a problem, but the misspelling generates an error that makes is clear where the issue is. Without the invocation, there will be no feedback from the code...it just won't run.

Comment: Thanks i was lacking the invocation, the Enemy constructor was already made...also the link was great, for clarify me other questions I had